# Aptana and Titanium menu bar problem with Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: unity, appmenu

After upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10 I have problems with Aptana and Titanium IDE. The menu bar doesn't work normally. Only one menu works, in Aptana the "Window" menu, in Titanium the "Run" menu. Other menus look empty.

Aptana:

[image]

Titanium:

[image]

Also HUD doesn't search in those menus.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: I was having the exact same issue here. I've updated Aptana. I also had some errors, so I followed the instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379490/aptana-studio-3-as-plugin-fails-to-startup Which fixed those errors... However the empty menu dropdown issue persists. I'm very interested in a fix to this, even if it means uninstalling and reinstalling aptana! I'm on Ubuntu 3.10 as well.

Comment: Related bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdbusmenu/+bug/618587

Answer (score 4):

Here is what worked for me:

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
```

update it to:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Eclipse
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= eclipse
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Type=Application
Categories=IDE;Development
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow
[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
Name=New Window
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= eclipse
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Answer (score 3):

For me this worked for Aptana 3.4.2

```
sudo -H gedit ~/.local/share/applications/aptana3.desktop
```

Path depends on how you have installed Aptana. It could also be in `/usr/share/applications/`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=3.0
Name=Aptana Studio 3
Comment=My Favorite IDE
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= /home/xxx/Programs/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3
Icon=/home/xxx/Programs/Aptana_Studio_3/icon_64x64.xpm
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;IDE;Development;
```

Important to note : **`Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= /home/xxx/Programs/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3`**

Change your `Exec` property and put the path to your Aptana launch file.

This will override your Unity menu and you will have a result like this:

[image]

Menus will be inside of your window, with all drop-downs working.

Comment: works for android ADT too, with little changes obviously. Thanks!