# Is there a way to enable the Eclipse global menu bar?

Tags: unity, eclipse, appmenu

I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 and it is working fine, but my Eclipse menu bar is not integrating with the Unity global menu bar, thus, I can't perform any operation in Eclipse.

I have tried various command like modifying `libappmenu` from vim. But Eclipse entries  were not found for modification.

Is there a way to enable the Eclipse global menu bar?

Comment: Same problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/361189/aptana-titanium-menu-bar-problem-with-ubuntu-13-10?noredirect=1#comment463018_361189

Comment: I reported this issue in ubuntu launchpad, for more information please see the [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-appmenu/+bug/1243211). if you want to get notified when the bug gets fixed you can subscribe to it by clicking on *Edit bug mail* there.